# How to access leaflet map object?

Tags: angularjs

How do I get access to leaflet map object.

e.g I have created a leaflet map using directive but now I want to access it's object to perform operations on it in the parent controller.

Comment: how about some code?

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this. Inject leafletData in to your controller.
Now in your controller you will have access to map object this way.

```
leafletData.getMap().then(function(map) {
$log.info("Got access to map object. Invalidating size");
map.invalidateSize();
```

});

Answer (score 0):

Add Directive name in your Html code

< `here add your directive name`     div id="map">